# Execute SQL file in Perl

Tags: sql, perl

We have a Perl script which runs a SQL and puts data in the table.
Now instead of supplying a single SQL statement, we want to pass bunch of them putting them together in a .sql file. We know that our program will fail because it expects a single SQL statement, not s bunch of them (that too from a .sql file). How do we make it work with a .sql file (having multiple INSERT statements?). We are using the DBI package.

A small snippet of code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("/home/user1/tools/mytest.sql");
$sth->execute || warn "Couldn't execute statement";
$sth->finish();
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945584/is-it-possible-to-execute-multiple-statements-in-a-single-query-using-dbdoracle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232950/perl-dbi-run-sql-script-with-multiple-statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want...

Once you create a DBI object, you can use it over and over again. Here I'm reading SQL statement after SQL statement from a file and processing each and every one in order:

```
use DBI;

my $sqlFile = "/home/user1/tools/mytest.sql"

my $dbh = DBI::Connect->new($connect, $user, $password)
    or die("Can't access db");

# Open the file that contains the various SQL statements
# Assuming one SQL statement per line

open (SQL, "$sqlFile")
    or die("Can't open file $sqlFile for reading");

# Loop though the SQL file and execute each and every one.
while (my $sqlStatement = <SQL>) {
   $sth = dbi->prepare($sqlStatement)
      or die("Can't prepare $sqlStatement");

   $sth->execute()
      or die("Can't execute $sqlStatement");
}
```

Notice that I'm putting the SQL statement in the `prepare` and not the file name that contains the SQL statement. Could that be your problem?

Comment: here i m calling dq.sql file in perl script in which i m passing variable like $patch_name ,$svn_url, $ftp_path which is defined in perl file but db.sql file is not accessing those variable? pls help me out asap.`$sqlfile = "C:/BuildScript/YellowBox_Script/YellowBox_Core_Script/db.sql";open(SQL, "$sqlfile") or die("Can't open file $sqlFile for reading");

while ($sqlStatement = <SQL>) 
{
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlStatement)
     or die ("Can't prepare $sqlStatement");

   $sth->execute()
      or die ("Can't execute $sqlStatement");
}`

Comment: @picnic4u: Can you create a question instead of a comment? Others will see it, and can help you.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this assumes one statement per line, which is hardly guaranteed.

Comment: @BradMace You're correct, and I've stated that in my comments. They didn't give me the format of the file, so I took the simplest arrangement. The point of my answer is that they needed to loop through the file, and do a prepare and execute of each statement.

Comment: Hi David W i have a similar doubt can you pls answer my question in the link below ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645801/how-to-execute-a-pl-sql-file-from-a-perl-script/25648856?noredirect=1#comment40077860_25648856

Answer (score 7):

There is a sort of workaround for DDL. You need to slurp SQL file first and then enclose it's contents into `BEGIN ... END;` keywords. Like:

```perl
sub exec_sql_file {
    my ($dbh, $file) = @_;

    my $sql = do {
        open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
        local $/;
        <$fh>
    };

    $dbh->do("BEGIN $sql END;");
}
```

This subroutine allows to run DDL (SQL) scripts with multiple statements inside (e.g. database dumps).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need perl for this at all. Just use the mysql command line client:

`mysql -h [hostname] -u[username] -p[password] [database name] < /home/user1/tools/mytest.sql`

replace the [variables] with your information.

**Note** no space after -u or -p. If your mysql server is running on the same machine you can omit -h[hostname] (it defaults to localhost)

Comment: Hi Cfreak, actually Its a script that doesnt bunch of other stuff too, so we need the modification is this script. Thanks for the solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've done it. In my case I dont assume one SQL per line and I assume, my example is a bit better :)

```
sub get_sql_from_file {
    open my $fh, '<', shift or die "Can't open SQL File for reading: $!";
    local $/;
    return <$fh>;
};

my $SQL = get_sql_from_file("SQL/file_which_holds_sql_statements.sql");
my $sth1 = $dbh1->prepare($SQL);
$sth1->execute();
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `get_sql_from_file` return the SQL, rather than setting a global variable? Global variables are bad.

Comment: It could return the SQL, but why do you think that using $SQL variable is bad in that example? Can you explain it? did you mean that using of global variables is a bad idea in general?

Comment: Global variables are, in general, a bad idea. Your functions will be easier to reuse if they are self-contained and don't assume the existence of external variables.

Comment: ok, thanks. I haven't been writting on perl at least for last 3 years and I'm currently trying to remember its concepts. Thanks for your comments

Comment: This is not a Perl concept. It's just programming practice - no matter which language you are using.

Comment: I realize this answer has been improved over time, `get_sql_from_file` has ended up as a simple slurp. Just do: `my $SQL = Path::Tiny->new("SQL/file_which_holds_sql_statements.sql")->slurp;` – oh and you need to make sure DBI allows more than one statement. Unsure if this is allowed by default nowadays.