# How to run and link a .sql file from Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am looking for a way to implement MySQL and Perl to make a program. Where I'm lost is that I have a .sql file, that creates 3 tables for the Perl program to use. How do you:

1) Execute the file fileName.sql in Perl to create the tables

2) Link those created tables into manipulable variables in Perl Program (like an example being able to add a user to one of the tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl you use the [DBI](http://dbi.perl.org/) database interface.  In your case, you will also be using something like the [`DBD::MySQL`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ecapttofu/DBD-mysql-4.022/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) driver.

There is lots of help available on this topic (including lots of questions on this site).

As for the specific question of your .sql file, there are a few approaches you could take, depending on how fancy you want to get:

- You could just copy and paste the commands into your program as you write it.
- You could execute an external program that will run the .sql file (for example, by using [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)).
- You could programmatically read in the .sql file and send the commands from within your program. A module could help you with this (I found [`SQL::Script`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eadamk/SQL-Script-1.06/lib/SQL/Script.pm) on CPAN, which looks useful, though I don't have any experience with it).

I suggest you pick an approach, try it, and ask if you have any specific problems.

Comment: I've managed to connect my program to MySQL now, but I'm still struggling getting my Perl program to run the .sql file to make the tables. Is there a DBI command like the DBI->*** that would do the trick?

Comment: Would it be simpler to just open the .sql file and read into an array and then form that array into a variable to send to DBI->prepare(***)?

Comment: @JamesBrown, if your file includes a single statement on each line, you could go through the file and execute each line.  Here is an example answer that does that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4220824/1584772.  Or you could split the file based on the SQL statement delimiter (e.g. semicolon).  Neither of these approaches is very robust: they could be broken by comments, a semicolon within a string, etc.  However, they would be ok if you know that the contents of the file won't break them.  If you want a more general solution, I suggest trying the module above.

Answer (score 3):

> Execute the file fileName.sql in Perl to create the tables

Usually you would set up the database in advance and use the command line `mysql` client or a GUI such as PHPMyAdmin to load the .sql file.

You could use a call to [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) to do the former though.

> Link those created tables into manipulable variables in Perl Program

Low level access to databases in Perl is usually handled via the [DBI module](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI).

Getting something along the lines of a variable per table calls for an ORM. [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass) is a popular choice for this.