# how to run a sql(.sql file) via perl script

Tags: sql, oracle, perl, shell

Hi i have a sql file(test.sql) something as simple as ,

```
select emp_id from employees 
where country='xxx'
and department='sales'
```

i know how to call this sql using a shell script, we normally use

```
#/bin/ksh

sqlplus $login $password test.sql
```

so my shell will call this sql and i spool this into a file. But how to do the same using a perl script.

I'm totally new to perl script and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to directly execute the sql file without first writing a perl script which takes the path to your sql file as a parameter then executes it. Here is a question which explains how to do (in perl):

[Execute SQL file in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217306/execute-sql-file-in-perl)

However, if you just want to execute the sql file there are easier ways to do that. Feel free to clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish other than executing this with perl instead of ksh - we might be able to provide more insight :).

Answer (score 0):

On a very basic level you could just call a system command as shown below.

Assuming your Oracle environment variables are set up in the user and sqlplus can be found on the $PATH

```
my $login     = "fred";
my $password  = "secretword";
my $sqlfile   = "/path/to/test.sql";

my @sql_array = system("sqlplus $login $password $sqlfile");
```

I chose to store the results in an array so that you could traverse each element (row) in turn

```
foreach my $row ( @sql_array )
{
    print $row;
}
```

There may be much better ways to do this but keeping it basic when learning Perl, I always found the `system()` command to be a good friend. Using Perl arrays is my chosen method of reading in output from a system command.

You may find other bits of spurious data in the array (sqlplus  but you can prune these out with regular expressions in the foreach loop.