# How to load the .sql file from perl script and execute the sql commands in the perl script

Tags: sql, perl, oop, dbi

I has to load SQL file within the perl script and execute the SQL commands and show output in perl file only.

Scenario:
test1.sql file contains SQL command in this format

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

Now I want to load the test1.sql without using files and Execute this SQL 
and also shows output in the Perl script like table created

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/simple-database-access-using-perl-dbi-and-sql

Comment: Use Perl DBI unless you've got a solid reason not to do so. If you have a solid reason, you should have said that in the question in the first place, so you can't have a solid reason not to use DBI, so that is what you should use.  It's not clear how you can avoid using files if the SQL statement is in a file.  Information like 'table created' is trickier.

Comment: Could this solve your problem ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217306/execute-sql-file-in-perl

Comment: No That wont works to me...

Comment: Actually I want to load the file which contains SQL statements and should perform operation atleast update,delete,create with database,

Comment: What won't work for you?  DBI, or the suggested question?  If you can't use DBI, you're largely on your own — that is _the_ Perl way of executing SQL (to the extent there's ever one way of doing things in Perl).  Have fun with an alternative, but you're going to need to research it.  Amongst other things, you'll need to identify the DBMS you're using — DBI has the merit of working with many different DBMS via its DBD::YourDBMSHere drivers.

Comment: Yes I tried DBI module and also sugggested link also wont work to me..

Comment: You tried DBI … and did you have the correct DBD module installed?  In what way did it fail?  It feels like you're being deliberately obtuse and declining to provide any useful information in the question.  Please update the question with information such as which DBMS you're using, and why you think DBI won't work, and why you think the alternative question (which leads to multiple other related questions) won't work for you, or can't be modified until they do work for you.  You can't expect an answer that you can simply copy'n'paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read your problem correctly, your biggest challenge is breaking apart the file into separate sql statements, [SQL::SplitStatement](http://search.cpan.org/~emazep/SQL-SplitStatement-1.00020/lib/SQL/SplitStatement.pm) is usefull but beware it's not bullet proof.

Here's an example of how you could accomplish this;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use DBI;
use File::Slurp;
use SQL::SplitStatement;

my $sql_blob = read_file( 'test1.sql' ) ;
my @sql_list = SQL::SplitStatement->new()->split($sql_blob);

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:mysql:my_database:localhost:3306", "username", "password" );
foreach my $sql (@sql_list) {
  print 'Executing ', $sql;
  $dbh->do($sql) or print "Can't do ", $dbh->errstr;
}
```

Comment: Cant locate SQL/Splitstatement.pm Uncaught exception from user code:
        Can't locate SQL/SplitStatement.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Dwimperl/p
erl/site/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .) at testsql.pl l
ine 15.

Comment: You will need to install the module, from the command line run 'cpan SQL::SplitStatement'

Answer (score 1):

The CPAN module [DBIx::RunSQL](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::RunSQL) maybe helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBIx::RunSQL;

my $test_dbh = DBIx::RunSQL->create(
    dsn     => 'dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:',
    sql     => 'test1.sql',
    force   => 1,
    verbose => 1,
);
```

Change the DBI dsn as your needs (also add `user` and `password` params)

Comment: This is a little scary, looking at the source code it [blindly splits](https://github.com/Corion/DBIx--RunSQL/blob/master/lib/DBIx/RunSQL.pm#L412) on ';\n'  - I would avoid anything that doesn't use a proper tokenizer.

Comment: To date, it suited my needs. In any case, the module author says about `split_sql` subroutine: "It is documented because it is not a very smart subroutine and you might want to override or replace it"